# Determine the element which previously had focus?

Tags: python, pyqt5, focus

In Java a `FocusEvent` has a method `getOppositeComponent()` which is where the focus came from or went to.

In PyQt5 is there any way to find what previously had focus when overriding `focusInEvent`?

As explained in a note, I want to be able to start an edit session automatically when the table view gets focus, end an edit session by going Ctrl-E in the cell, leaving focus in the table view but without triggering another edit session.

MRE (using clunky added-attribute mechanism):

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class TableViewDelegate( QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate ):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        # QPlainTextEdit for multi-line text cells... 
        editor = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit( parent )
        table_view = parent.parent()
        def end_edit():
            print( f'end_edit...' )
            # clunky mechanism 
            table_view.do_not_start_edit = True
            self.closeEditor.emit( editor )
            
        self.end_edit_shortcut = QtWidgets.QShortcut( 'Ctrl+E', editor, context = QtCore.Qt.ShortcutContext.WidgetShortcut )
        self.end_edit_shortcut.activated.connect( end_edit )
        return editor

class TableViewModel( QtCore.QAbstractTableModel ):
    def __init__( self ):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = [
            [ 1, 2, ],
            [ 3, 4, ],
        ]
    
    def rowCount( self, *args ):
        return len( self._data )
    
    def columnCount(self, *args ):
        return 2
    
    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            # print( f'data... {self._data[index.row()][index.column()]}')
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
        
    def flags( self, index ):
        result = super().flags( index )
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEditable | result
    
class TableView( QtWidgets.QTableView ):
    def __init__(self ):
        super().__init__()
        self.setTabKeyNavigation( False )
        self.setItemDelegate( TableViewDelegate() ) 
    
    def focusInEvent( self, event ):
        print( f'table view focus-in event')
        super().focusInEvent( event )
        
        if hasattr( self, 'do_not_start_edit' ):
            print( f'start of edit vetoed...')
            del self.do_not_start_edit
            return
        
        n_rows = self.model().rowCount()
        if n_rows == 0:
            return
        # go to last row, col 1
        cell1_index = self.model().index( n_rows - 1, 1 )
        self.edit( cell1_index )

class MainWindow( QtWidgets.QMainWindow ):
    def __init__( self ):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle( 'Editor focus MRE' )
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.table_view = TableView()
        table_label = QtWidgets.QLabel( '&Table' )
        layout.addWidget( table_label )
        table_label.setBuddy( self.table_view )
        layout.addWidget( self.table_view )
        self.table_view.setModel( TableViewModel() )
        edit_box = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget( edit_box )
        centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget( self )
        centralwidget.setLayout( layout )
        self.setCentralWidget( centralwidget )
        self.setGeometry( QtCore.QRect(400, 400, 400, 400) )
        
        edit_box.setFocus()
                
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
main_window = MainWindow()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Start by going Alt-T: this moves focus to the `QTableView` and starts an edit of the bottom-right cell. Enter some text, and then press Ctrl-E. This stops the edit session and because of the clunky attribute `do_not_start_edit`, a new edit session is (as desired) vetoed. Another way to end the edit session is to click in the `QLineEdit`, for example.

I'm not sure that this rather clunky "added attribute" mechanism works in all circumstances.  In fact it seems to work a bit better than I at first thought, hence this MRE... To me it doesn't seem very elegant.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225059/discussion-on-question-by-mike-rodent-determine-the-element-which-previously-had).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, I think, to use [QApplication.focusChanged( old, new )](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#focusChanged), as alluded to by Musicamante in a comment, and combine this with overriding [QStyledItemDelegate.destroyEditor( editor, index )](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#destroyEditor) so that instead of destroying the editor component it is re-used each time `createEditor` is called (lazy instantiation with first call). It is then trivial to detect when focus passes from the editor component to the `QTableView`.

This "re-usable editor component" technique is fairly well-known in Java Swing (and probably JavaFX). It appears to work fine in PyQt5: modified MRE:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class TableViewDelegate( QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate ):
    def __init__( self, *args, **kvargs ):
        super().__init__( *args, **kvargs )
        self.editor = None
    
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        if not self.editor:  
            self.editor = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit( parent )
            def end_edit():
                self.closeEditor.emit( self.editor )
            self.end_edit_shortcut = QtWidgets.QShortcut( 'Ctrl+E', 
                self.editor, context = QtCore.Qt.ShortcutContext.WidgetShortcut )
            self.end_edit_shortcut.activated.connect( end_edit )
        return self.editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index ):
        existing_text = index.model().data( index, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole )
        editor.document().setPlainText( str( existing_text ) )            
    
    def destroyEditor( self, editor, index ):
        index.model().setData( index, editor.document().toPlainText() )
        editor.clear()

class TableViewModel( QtCore.QAbstractTableModel ):
    def __init__( self ):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = [[ 1, 2, ], [ 3, 4, ],]
    def rowCount( self, *args ):
        return len( self._data )
    def columnCount(self, *args ):
        return 2
    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
    def setData(self, index, value, role = QtCore.Qt.EditRole ):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            self._data[ index.row() ][ index.column() ] = value
    def flags( self, index ):
        result = super().flags( index )
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEditable | result
    
class TableView( QtWidgets.QTableView ):
    def __init__(self ):
        super().__init__()
        self.setTabKeyNavigation( False )
        self.setItemDelegate( TableViewDelegate() ) 
        
    def focus_changed( self, old, new ):
        print( f'table view focus change old {old} new {new}')
        if new == self:
            editor_component = self.itemDelegate().editor
            if old == None or old != editor_component:
                n_rows = self.model().rowCount()
                if n_rows == 0:
                    return
                # go to last row, col 1
                cell1_index = self.model().index( n_rows - 1, 1 )
                self.edit( cell1_index )
            else:
                print( 'edit command VETOED' )

class MainWindow( QtWidgets.QMainWindow ):
    def __init__( self ):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle( 'Editor focus MRE' )
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.table_view = TableView()
        table_label = QtWidgets.QLabel( '&Table' )
        layout.addWidget( table_label )
        table_label.setBuddy( self.table_view )
        layout.addWidget( self.table_view )
        self.table_view.setModel( TableViewModel() )
        edit_box = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget( edit_box )
        centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget( self )
        centralwidget.setLayout( layout )
        self.setCentralWidget( centralwidget )
        self.setGeometry( QtCore.QRect(400, 400, 400, 400) )
        
        edit_box.setFocus()
                
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

main_window = MainWindow()
app.focusChanged.connect( main_window.table_view.focus_changed )

main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to start editing a cell only after specific focus in events, you have to check the [`reason()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfocusevent.html#reason) of the event.

A problem with your approach is that you're using the buddy feature of the label to set the focus, which might be an issue if you want to start editing whenever the shortcut is activated. If the table already has focus, it cannot receive a focusInEvent.

In order to achieve this, you can create a QAction with the wanted shortcut, add it to the widget and create a dedicated function in the table to start editing. Then you can "simulate" the mnemonic effect on the label using html tags.

```
class TableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setTabKeyNavigation(False)
    
    def startEdit(self):
        n_rows = self.model().rowCount()
        if n_rows:
            cell1_index = self.model().index(n_rows - 1, 1)
            self.edit(cell1_index)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...
        table_label = QtWidgets.QLabel('<u>T</u>able')
        layout.addWidget(table_label)
        # this is not necessary anymore...
        # table_label.setBuddy(self.table_view)

        self.startEditAction = QtWidgets.QAction(self)
        self.startEditAction.setShortcut('alt+t')
        self.startEditAction.triggered.connect(self.table_view.startEditLastCell)
        self.addAction(self.startEditAction)
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this is addressing the issue in hand. In fact editing a cell in the table is very easy with the default shortcut F2, so I'm unconcerned with being able to use the "buddy" shortcut when focus is already in the table. Indeed surely the point of a "buddy" shortcut is precisely navigation.  But in my MCE the thing which initiates editing is the fact of receiving focus. That's what I want.

Comment: I had also spotted the `reason` method of `QFocusEvent`. It looks like this is not a good fit: the reason when focus returns from the editor component to the `QTableView` is `OtherFocusReason`. This is not specific enough: I'm sure other scenarios could give this reason.

Comment: So, the buddy shortcut was actually unnecessary for the example, and you only want to start edit when focusing in, but *not* when editing is complete?

Comment: The reason I added a buddy shortcut was because I'm a keyboard purist: when I put together an app I want people to be able to use it without taking their fingers off the keyboard ever, unless there's a really good reason, and I also don't like forcing people to have to tab multiple times to focus into a component.

Comment: Couple of points: I have now used the `reason()` method (better than a clunky attribute), but I regard this as a workaround. Also, in Java, although the normal thing with a delegate + editor component is to create a new one each time you start editing, it is perfectly acceptable practice just to have one editor component which you re-use, hence the practicality of using `getOppositeComponent`. I read in the Qt5 documentation that `destroyEditor` can be re-implemented. I might have explored that, but as it's not possible to find where focus has come from, this solution is not so good.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I hadn't made that clear: the whole reason for my question is that when I end the edit by pressing the shortcut combo it doesn't end because another focus-in event is caused in the `QTableView`. I want to veto that. Yes, the buddy setup wasn't necessary, that's true: tabbing into the table would have been sufficient.

Comment: Upon rethinking the whole issue, I've some doubts about the wanted behavior. Automatic edit start by mouse click can be done using the `SelectedClicked` edit trigger and eventually implementing the `mousePressEvent` when no valid index is clicked. If you need edit start on focus in events, why don't you just start editing when the focus event reason is a `TabFocusReason` or `BacktabFocusReason`? If that's not enough, please clarify the *whole* process with possible scenarios, as it's still not clear to me what you *do* want, what you *don't* want, and *when*.

Comment: I'm currently filtering OUT on `reason == OtherFocusReason`, with all other reasons causing edit of cell at col 1 on the last row. This seems to produce pretty much the desired behaviour although I consider it to be suboptimal and a workaround. I think I've described pretty much what I want. In fact the answer "no, in Qt5 you can't get the previous focus component" would have sufficed for the original question.

Comment: @mikerodent sorry, but that's wrong again. In Qt you cannot *directly* get the previous focus widget from the focusIn event, but there are ways to get it, and that's why we asked for more context. In your case is not a requirement, as checking the reason is not only *not* a workaround, but is also the preferred choice and far from being suboptimal from the framework's perspective. For other more complex situations, you should consider the [QApplication.focusChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#focusChanged) signal instead.

Comment: `OtherFocusReason` is not specific enough: the clue's in the name. For me it is a workaround. You're free to think otherwise. `QApplication.focusChanged`, which I didn't know about, and which I consider probably to be the answer to my question, might indeed work if I override the delegate's `destroyEditor` so that I re-use the editor component. I've previously alluded to both these ideas.